# Firebase database data aggregation

Tags: firebase, join, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

Let's take a look at "Instagram-like" app, as an example.

In the feed we got posts, with user avatar and name at the top, photo or video below, and last comments, likes count and post time at the bottom.

Basically, at the client I'm waiting to get from backend something like

`{
username: "John",
avatar:"some_link",
photo:"photo_url",
likes:"9",
time:"182937428",
comments:[comments there]
}`

but using Firebase, I need to store data in more flat way. so there will be "users", "posts" and "comments" in data JSON.

How am I suppose to aggregate data from those nodes in some kind of single object, which is easy to use at client?

Or should I ask Firebase for posts, than for all users in it, and for all their comments, and do aggregation after all three 'requests' are done?

Answer (score 1):

You should implement "shallow" tree structure, and use references where needed. 
That means that for most cases in your app you should use the object as at is, Making sure that it contain the "essential data" (in the example below "the chat title"), and keys for "further" information (in the example, keys to the "members").

from firebase docs (https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data):

**bad**

```
{
  // This is a poorly nested data architecture, because iterating the children
  // of the "chats" node to get a list of conversation titles requires
  // potentially downloading hundreds of megabytes of messages
  "chats": {
    "one": {
      "title": "Historical Tech Pioneers",
      "messages": {
        "m1": { "sender": "ghopper", "message": "Relay malfunction found. Cause: moth." },
        "m2": { ... },
        // a very long list of messages
      }
    },
    "two": { ... }
  }
}
```

**good**

```
{
  // Chats contains only meta info about each conversation
  // stored under the chats's unique ID
  "chats": {
    "one": {
      "title": "Historical Tech Pioneers",
      "lastMessage": "ghopper: Relay malfunction found. Cause: moth.",
      "timestamp": 1459361875666
    },
    "two": { ... },
    "three": { ... }
  },

  // Conversation members are easily accessible
  // and stored by chat conversation ID
  "members": {
    // we'll talk about indices like this below
    "one": {
      "ghopper": true,
      "alovelace": true,
      "eclarke": true
    },
    "two": { ... },
    "three": { ... }
  },

  // Messages are separate from data we may want to iterate quickly
  // but still easily paginated and queried, and organized by chat
  // conversation ID
  "messages": {
    "one": {
      "m1": {
        "name": "eclarke",
        "message": "The relay seems to be malfunctioning.",
        "timestamp": 1459361875337
      },
      "m2": { ... },
      "m3": { ... }
    },
    "two": { ... },
    "three": { ... }
  }
}
```

Comment: I still dont get it. So what if i got "user" with "avatar", "name", "age". And i got "post" with "url", "count" and "userId". How to get it together? Manually make a for-each for every "post" and add "user.avatar" and "user.name" to its on-the-client realisation? And what if yhere are thousands of posts?? Or should i duplicate data from user to post? And what if user changes name or avatar???